# Partial isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm following the first tutorial on api.rubyonrails.org.

However, I've finished the entire tutorial except for a specific problem I've skipped.
The following partial isn't working:

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/comment',
           :collection => @post.comments %>
```

For some reason, it throws the following error:

Missing partial comments/comment with

```
{:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "c:/rails/blog/app/views"
```

I don't quite understand what the purpose of :collection is(perhaps someone could elaborate).

You can find see the files on my github repo below:
http://github.com/imjp/blog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply misspelled the name of the partial:

```
_comment.html.errb
```

instead of:

```
_comment.html.erb
```

For the explanation of `collection` see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Para 3.4.5

Comment: Be sure it happens very often to all of us ;)